# How to view my ubuntu screen on my android phone

Tags: screen, screencast

My laptop's built in display is broken, and I don't have another monitor. I want to use my android phone as a monitor, using either usb cable or local wifi network (It should work offline, using hotspot without any data connection)

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging your laptop to your tv via hdmi. When you get to a purple screen press enter then type your password and press enter.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to use tv. I want to use android phone...

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if you can do that.